# Email not send in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am creating single page application in HTML.I am new to PHP. In that I have a Leave a comment Page. I have text box to enter the name and email. I have the button while clicking the button mail will be send to the user. I am writing the email code in PHP.

My Code is

HTML CODE

```
<div class="coment-form">
                        <h4>LEAVE YOUR COMMENT</h4>
                        <form  class="form" id='form' name='form' method="post" action="service.php">
                            <input type="text" name="name" value="Name :" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name :';}" required="">
                            <input type="email" name="email" value="Email (will not be published)* :" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email (will not be published)* :';}" required="">
                            <input type="text" name="cmt" value="Website :" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Website :';}" required="">
                            <textarea type="text" name="message" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your Comment...';}" required="">Your Comment...</textarea>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" >
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

PHP Code :

service.php file

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$name=$_POST['name'];

$email=$_POST['email'];

$cmt = $_POST['cmt'];
$message=$_POST['message'];


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {


//mail code
 $to = $_POST['email'];

$email_subject = "Dear $name";

$email_body = "Thank you for inquiring about our Services advertised on our webSite.
Each of the listed services we offer are uniquely different. 

One of our representatives will contact you soon, would help and appreciate if you can drop a line with a suitable 
Date and Time for a Phone / Skype discussion.

Once again, thank you for your interest in our services.

Cordially,

 ".






//mail code
// $email_to = "venkatj@acute.company";
 $email_to = "sbshnr@gmail.com";

$email_sub = "Enquiry from contact us form";

$email_bod = 
 "$name

 ".

 $headers = "From:nisha@acute.company";



mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
mail($email_to,$email_sub,$email_bod,$headers);


echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Thank you admin will contact you soon...!");window.location.assign("Contact_us.html");</script>';

//header('Location: contact.php');





?>
```

My problem is Email not send while clicking the button.

I Installed WaMp in My machine. It is in orange color while checking i got an error as

Your port 80 is actually used by

Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Is there any way to correct this error?

Can anyone please help me

Comment: You've got two dots (`.`) at the end of the lines. `.` are intended to concatenate strings.

Comment: are you working on local server (xampp, wampp etc) or online server

Comment: Check this http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Comment: Did you check the mail error logs.?

Comment: it is simply returning the page as such no function is working

Answer (score 0):

You need SMTP server OR mail service configured to send mails.

Comment: Is there any way to add mailservice

Comment: You can use `mail` function without SMTP

Comment: @Justinas you can use the function `mail` but the mail would not be sent.

Answer (score 0):

First you should add `name` to your submit button like this

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="Submit Comment" >
```

And when this is set you run your code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_form'])) {
  //Rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you haven't closed the if condition in the code

Answer (score 0):

"Port 80 already used" usually means that an other program is using this port.

First change your httpd.conf file (under Apache folder).
Find "ServerName" and change the default port ":80" by ":8080".
Then access localhost on your browser using "localhost/8080" instead of "localhost".

Then, to be able to send an email locally, you need to configure your server.
The easiest way is to install a soft like Fake Sendmail (http://glob.com.au/sendmail/) and follow the instructions.

It is pretty easy to configure, especially if the sender email is a gmail one (replace the stars by your informations):

```
[sendmail] 
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com 
smtp_port=587 
default_domain=gmail.com 
error_logfile=error.log 
auth_username=********@gmail.com 
auth_password=****** 
pop3_server= 
pop3_username= 
pop3_password= 
force_sender=****@gmail.com 
force_recipient= 
hostname=
```

You finally have to update your php.ini: find "sendmail_path" line and add the path to sendmail.exe.

Restart WAMP and it should work :)

Answer (score -1):

you need to complete header

```
$header = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header.= 'From: NAME <info@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
$header.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$header.= 'X-Priority: 3 \r\n';
```

mail function only work on server & not work in local host (it's showing errors)

Comment: what? :) What about mail catcher or defining SMTP server in app?